# Convert Milliseconds to Timestamp using Laravel and Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I have more than 10000 records in my mongodb. Now i don't want to process code using php, hence i have created following query in laravel 5 which does all processing in mongodb and produce result very quickly.
Query is as follwos

```
 $result = Role::raw(function ($collection){
        return $collection->aggregate(array(
            array( '$match' => array( "PanelID" => "A00898" ) ),
            array( '$project' => array( 'EventTS' => 1, 'MainsPower' => 1, '_id' => 0 ) ),
            array(
                '$unwind' => array(
                    'path' => '$MainsPower',
                    'includeArrayIndex' => "arrayIndex",
                    'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
                )
            ),
            array(
                '$project' => array(
                    'MainsPower' => 1,
                    'timestamp' => array(
                        '$add' => array(
                            '$EventTS',
                            array( '$multiply' => array( 60000, '$arrayIndex' ) )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
    })->toArray();
```

Above Query produces result in following way

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MainsPower] => 255
            [timestamp] => MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime Object
                (
                    [milliseconds] => 1448911800000
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [MainsPower] => 0
            [timestamp] => MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime Object
                (
                    [milliseconds] => 1448911860000
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [MainsPower] => 0
            [timestamp] => MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime Object
                (
                    [milliseconds] => 1448911920000
                )

        )
}
```

But i want response in following way

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MainsPower] => 255
            [timestamp] => 2015-10-07T14:28:41.545Z


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [MainsPower] => 0
            [timestamp] => 2015-10-15T14:28:41.545Z
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [MainsPower] => 0
            [timestamp] => 2015-11-07T14:28:41.545Z


        )
}
```

I tried many solutions and aplied in laravel to convert in date formate but it gives following error

```
MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime not found
```

Comment: [Try this](https://gist.github.com/jonmilsom/75e871c513604d1193a1)

Comment: @HimanshuRaval i try to use but given error as follows
"Argument 1 passed to getUnixTimestampFromMongoUTCDateTime() must be an instance of MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime, string given,"

Comment: @HimanshuRaval   i am using this way i hope this is correct way 
array(
                    '$project' => array(
                        'MainsPower' => 1,
                        getUnixTimestampFromMongoUTCDateTime('$EventTS'),
                        'timestamp' => array(
                            '$add' => array(
                                '$EventTS',
                                array( '$multiply' => array( 60000, '$arrayIndex' ) )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )

Comment: @HimanshuRaval my code is fine or i have to make changes in my code. Please help me i totally stuck :( :(

Comment: Please check here [check this](http://www.litphp.info/fatal_error_class_39_mongodate39_not_found_when_using_mongodb_php_driver_1_1_2_and_php_7_0)   . you will get idea how to use it.

Comment: @HimanshuRaval I have check above link and applied to my problem but did not work got following error
"Undefined constant 'MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime'"

Comment: @all no one idea how to slove??